# Display product in list using widgets in magento

Tags: magento, widget

I am working on magento home page and need display products on home page. I have used widgets to display products. I want to display product in list one by one but it shows in grid. Right now I am showing the products in list.

my code is :-

```
{{widget type="highlight/product_popular" title="special" products_count="3"   template="highlight/product/grid.phtml" class_name="highlight-popular"}}
```

Using this code the product is shown in grid but actually I want to display it in list like:-
 1. Product1
 2. product2

Please, suggest how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

whatever you are putting in your grid.phtml - change it as suggested in

`base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

as per list mode, code followed by it